# Token en Web API 2 - donde se guarda la información?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Buenas.

Quiero saber si pueden sacarme una inquietud que estoy teniendo en el desarrollo de una API con WEB API 2.

Decidimos con mi equipo implementar la autenticación basada en token.

Una vez que el usuario se registra y luego el token es generado, esa información (token, desde, hasta etc) donde queda persistida?

No veo que se guarde nada en las tablas del modelo Identity (AspNetxx).

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El token se genera en base a los claims, cuando expones el endpoint usando el codigo

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    // Note: Remove the following line before you deploy to production:
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};

// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Importante es la primer linea donde defines el `/Token` desde este es que el cliente consume el servicio que le devolvera el token que requiere para poder se autorizado en las llamadas a los demas request.
Por eso no persiste sino que es algo temporal que usaras para invocar a los servicio de webapi que requieran autenticacion.

[Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Por un lado esta la registración del usuario, y por otro esta como pides un token para poder realizar los request a los servicio webapi marcados conn `[Authorize]`.
Del artículo analiza el titulo "Configuring the Authorization Server" allí explica como exponer el servicio de `/Token` como un endpoint para ser consumido por el cliente que requiere un token de autenticacion.

Cuando requieras invocar un servicio webapi debes enviar en el header ese token, el cual seguramente lo conserves en el `storage` del `html`.

[[ASPNET Web API] Trabajando con bearer token en Web API](http://www.julitogtu.com/2015/09/07/aspnet-web-api-autenticacion-basica/)

En este segundo ejemplo veras como se envia el token como `Bearer` en el header.

Por eso por un lado tienes los datos del usuario para validar el acceso y por otro el sistema de autorizacion usando tokens.

---

**>>1) Si el token no se persiste y se genera dinámicamente... Cada vez que se haga un request y se pase el token por heder (autorization) contra que lo compara?**

Entiendo que aqui es donde entran en juego los claims ya que la info que asignes sera usada para generar el token. Si analiza el ejemplo del primer link veras una linea que define

```
Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
```

El código que implementa lo podrias analizar de `github`

[ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs](https://github.com/MikeWasson/LocalAccountsApp/blob/master/LocalAccountsApp/Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs)

Podras localizar la validacion de las credenciales del usuario

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

Y como genera los `Claims` que definiran al `token`.

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Del lado del servicio webapi cuando le llega el token validara su vigencia, pero no las credenciales del usuario, eso ya lo realizo cuando se solicito el token. Entre el cliente que recibe el token y el servidor que lo genera no hay comunicacion.

**>>2) Que pasa si se realiza un reset del iis?**

El token tiene el tiempo de expiración, es mas cuando se define el `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` se puede especificar este valor

```
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14)
```

Aunque la idea es que sea lo mas pequeña posible, por eso se recomienda que analices implementar el `RefreshToken`

[AngularJS: Enable OWIN Refresh Tokens Using ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/angularjs-enable-owin-refresh-tokens-using-asp-net-web-api/)

Como comenta @rsciriano si reinicias el servicio de IIS del cliente el token aun sera válido.

Comment: Excelente explicación. Muchas gracias. Ahora, en base a tu respuesta es que me surgen 2 preguntas: 1) Si el token no se persiste y se genera dinámicamente... Cada vez que se haga un request y se pase el token por heder (autorization) contra que lo compara?. 2) Que pasa si se realiza un reset del iis?

Comment: Muy buena explicación. Yo tampoco estaba seguro de como se gestionaban los `tokens` y he realizado unas pruebas con el proyecto que habías enlazado. En ellas he visto que no se almacenas sino que se envían cifradas incluyendo los `Claims` de la identidad del usuario. He añadido una nueva respuesta explicándolo.

Comment: @rsciriano a mi tambien me pico la duda, voy a editar mi respuesta para dar algo de precisión en la respuesta. La explicación que has realizado tambien es muy completa

Answer (score 4):

El `Token` no se almacena en servidor, sino que se envía cifrado al cliente y contiene toda la información necesaria para identificarlo y para controlar su validez.

Cuando, desde cliente, se realiza una petición enviando el `Token`, el servidor lo descifra, comprueba su validez y establece el contexto de seguridad con los datos incluidos en el.

Puedes hacer una prueba de este comportamiento usando el proyecto ["Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login"](https://github.com/MikeWasson/LocalAccountsApp) que ha enlazado @Leandro-Tuttini en su respuesta *(a mi me ha ayudado a terminar de comprender todo esto)*.

- Lo primero sería hacer una prueba sin modificar nada, capturamos el tráfico de la autenticación y nos copiamos el `Token` que ha devuelto
- Después modificamos el método `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` añadiendo un Claim adicional con un `loremImsum`

  ```
  public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
  {
      // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
      var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
      // Add custom user claims here
      userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("loremImsum", @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
      ));

      return userIdentity;
  }
  ```
- Al volver a probar, vemos como el tamaño del `Token` ha crecido porque está incluyendo el nuevo `Claim`, es decir, **el `Token` incluye todos los `Claims` de la identidad del usuario**

Este artículo "[Simple explanation of bearer authentication for Web Api 2](http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2014/08/simple-explanation-of-bearer-authentication-for-web-api-2.html)" (en inglés) es muy interesante porque explican paso a paso como funciona la autenticación `Bearer` y una de las cosas que mencionan es que el `Token` no de guarda en servidor sino que se envía cifrado.

También he comprobado que una vez autenticado, si paras el sitio y lo vuelves a arrancar, puedes seguir haciendo peticiones usando el `Token` que tienes guardado (es capaz de descifrarlo y sigue siendo válido). Por eso, una de las recomendaciones que hacen en el artículo, es que la validez del `Token` sea muy corta.

Otra de las cosas que hay que tener en cuenta es el [DataProtectorTokenProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613292(v=vs.108).aspx) que se usa para cifrar los Tokens porque el que se usa por defecto se basa en claves del servidor local por lo que no funcionaría en un entorno de balanceo de carga *(en estos entornos se podría usar uno basado en certificados)*