# Consumir servicio Web RESTful en ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, oauth, rest

Tengo una situación, debo consumir un servicio Web RESTful con autenticación OAuth2 y mi aplicación está desarrollada sobre ASP.NET.

¿Qué puedo usar para consumir este servicio?, ¿cómo debo crear el cliente utilizando librerías como OWIN u otras?

Comment: te recomiendo usar RestSharp , es muy sencillo para la comunicacion con APIS por medio de Oauth http://restsharp.org/ Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si el servidor expone servicio webapi marcado con el atributo `[Authorize]` el primer paso será obtener un token que permita ingresar a los servicios.

Recomendaría le des una mirada a este artículo

[Garantizar una Web API con cuentas individuales y el inicio de sesión Local en ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Como entenderás desde la webapi se expone un endpoint como `/Token` es al cual debes realizar la primer llamada para obtener el `token` que debes enviar a los demás servicios cuando los invoques

Desde asp.net podrias trabajar de dos formas

- usando jquery por medio de `$.ajax` enviar en el header de la llamada enviando el token

  [Token Based Authentication Using Web API 2: Part 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/token-based-authentication-using-web-api-2/)

importante como defines en el header el token

```
var headers = {};  
if (token) {  
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;  
}  

$.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        url: '/api/values',  
        headers: headers  
}).done(function (data) {  
        self.result(data);  
}).fail(showError);
```

- usando la clase HttpClient

  [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Como entenderás se requiere un paso previo para obtener el `token` que te dará acceso a los servicios.

Comment: Leandro muchas gracias, ¿Puedes tal vez indicarme como obtener el token? ese token me imagino debo almacenarlo en DB y utilizarlo cada vez que consuma el WS o debo solicitar un token nuevo cada vez que lo haga?

Comment: @J.Guevara el token lo obtienes por los medios que hemos comentado, invocando al enpoint /token que el servicio webapi seguro expone. Este token lo deberias conservar en el storage de html, no se guarda en ninguna db porque tiene un tiempo de expiracion, cuando vence debes solicitar otro

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a trabajarlo y comento el resultado. Excelentes respuestas Leandro.

Answer (score 1):

Para consumir un servicio **REST** desde `.NET` debes utilizar la clase [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). En este [enlace](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) tienes un ejemplo de como usarla (el código `C#` sería algo como esto)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```

En cuanto a la autenticación `OAuth` podrías usar la librería [`AsyncOAuth`](https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth) y después, cambiar la primera línea del código anterior para configurar el `HttpClient` de forma que gestione la autenticación con esta librería:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new OAuthMessageHandler(
    "consumerKey", 
    "consumerSecret", 
    new AccessToken("accessToken", "accessTokenSecret"))))
{
    ...
}
```

Según la documentación de esta librería, también hay que poner el siguiente código en el `Application_Start` para poder realizar operaciones criptográficas de cálculo de `HASH`

```
OAuthUtility.ComputeHash = (key, buffer) => { 
    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA1(key)) 
    { 
        return hmac.ComputeHash(buffer); 
    } 
};
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a aplicar lo que me han comentado y apenas tenga resultado lo haré saber.

Comment: @J.Guevara Encantado de poderte ayudar. Por cierto, ¿desde donde haces la llamada a la `API`? ¿desde **cliente**? ¿desde **servidor**? lo digo porque mi respuesta se aplica al caso en que la llamada sea desde servidor. ¿Quizás estas llamando a tu propia `API` en esta misma aplicación? En ese caso, @Leandro-Tuttini te lo comenta en su respuesta y tienes más detalles en [esta otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3583)

Comment: Desde el cliente, y muchas gracias por citar el tema del token, estaba algo confundido con este tema, estoy recién trabajando con esto además, como puedes ver soy nuevo en la comunidad.

Comment: @j.guevara estaría bien que editarlas tu pregunta aportando detalles que aclaren estos temas para que sea más útil al resto de usuarios. Saludos