# Crear cliente C# (ASP.NET) para consumir servicio web RESTFUL

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

Estoy en apuros ya hace un tiempo, por primera vez debo implementar un cliente en **C# (ASP.NET)** que consuma un servicio expuesto por una aplicación web para crear clientes. He revisado diferentes códigos en la web como:

- http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448690/how-to-consume-a-webapi-from-asp-net-web-api-to-store-result-in-database

pero la verdad me parece algo muy complejo para lo que necesito (aunque por lo que he comentado nunca he trabajado con este tema).

Tengo en mi poder las credenciales de autenticación de la aplicación (id y secret) para solicitar el token, la URI y la estructura para autenticarme y solicitar el token:

**Estructura**

http://id:secret@aplicacion/webservices/auth/token/

Espero que puedan ayudarme por favor, estoy algo desubicado y no se bien como comenzar este cliente, mis dudas son:

- con esta información, ¿como podría solicitar el token?
- cuando obtenga el token ¿Como proceso a enviarlo para obtener acceso a las funcionalidades del servicio web?

Se que la pregunta es muy coloquial, pero espero ser lo mas explicito y simple posible en mis descripciones.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, para poder responder a tu pregunta se necesitaría más detalles sobre el servicio que pretendes consumir ¿dispones de documentación o ejemplos? Supongo que lo tendrás que consumir desde servidor ¿no? Podrías echarle un vistazo a [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3672/602) pregunta porque es similar y hay dos respuestas, una para consumirlo desde cliente y otra desde servidor

Comment: la idea es invocar el servicio REST desde codigo .net ? si es asi porque usar la clase Httpclient (se mencina en el segundo link) dices que es complejo ? para mi seria el camino que deberias implementar

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder a ambos,@rsciriano para responder a las preguntas, poseo documentación sobre credenciales y la estructura que comento en la pregunta para consumir el servicio mas no ejemplos, el servicio lo debo consumir desde una aplicación web diferente a la que expone el servicio, respecto a la pregunta enlazada como respuesta, recalco que tengo una gran duda en cómo solicitar el token, no se a que se refieren con el header del token y si me lo pueden aclarar creo que seria de grandisima ayuda para mi. @Leandro Tuttini, si debo invocar el servicio desde codigo .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura de la url que estas poniendo `http://id:secret@aplicacion/webservices/auth/token/` se corresponde al protocolo de autenticación básica de HTTP en el que se envían el usuario y contraseña como texto plano.

Esa es la url funciona cuando la pones en el navegador pero con la clase [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) se hace de diferente manera.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
var tokenUrl = "http://aplicacion/webservices/auth/token/";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", 
    Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(tokenUrl);
HttpContent content = response.Content;

// ... Comprobar el código de estado                                 
Console.WriteLine("Response StatusCode: " + (int)response.StatusCode);

// ... Leer el token (en caso de que esté como texto plano)
string token = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Se supone que en `response.Content` tendrías el token solicitado aunque deberías de revisar la documentación para ver como te lo devuelven y cual el el formato

**Nota**: El ejemplo de código lo he sacado de [aquí](https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915) pero no he probado por mi mismo si funciona (aunque debería). En [esta](https://serverfault.com/a/371918) respuesta de ServerFault explican lo de la Url

Por cierto, cuando lo pongas en producción sería conveniente usar una conexión segura **SSL** porque el usuario y contraseña van en texto plano. El código debería funcionar simplemente cambiando `http` por `https`

Comment: estoy utilizando un código ejemplo @rscririano pero tengo dudas, adjunte el código con dudas como una respuesta si puedes ayudarme u otra persona lo agradeceria

Comment: Hola @JuanHurtado encantado de ayudarte de nuevo pero no debes hacer una pregunta añadiendo una respuesta. Tienes que añadir una nueva pregunta y eliminar la respuesta. Asegúrate en la nueva pregunta de darte un poco de contexto para que así te pueda ayudar más gente. Estaré atento a tu nueva pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @JuanHurtado, también puedes editar tu pregunta original añadiendo las nuevas dudas

Comment: está hecho, nueva pregunta, muchas gracias