# ¿Cómo debo estructurar una solicitud HttpWebRequest para autenticarme con OAuth 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

Debo consumir un servicio web rest con autenticación `Oauth2`, de lo cual tengo documentación (credenciales) pero no se como hacer la solicitud del token para lo que creo que debo hacer una solicitud http, sigo la temática de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5496/crear-cliente-c-asp-net-para-consumir-servicio-web-restful/5556?noredirect=1#comment11073_5556) , estoy usando el siguiente código

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sitio/webservices/auth/token/");

var postData = "grant_type=grant_type&username=username&password=password&id=id&secret=secret";

//    request.Headers.Add("id", "id");
//    request.Headers.Add("secret", "secret");

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Pero tengo dos preguntas puntuales sobre él y espero que me puedan ayudar.

1. La variable postData contiene los datos a enviar, no si deba enviarlas así o mas bien agregarlas como Headers como lo muestra el código que esta documentado o si debo enviar unas variables en forma de la variable postData y otros en forma headers, las varibles que tengo son credenciales de accesos, unas que identifica la aplicación porque es un servicio REST o sea un grand_type, id y un secret y las demás variables son autenticación de perfil de usuario.
2. La segunda pregunta es sobre el ContentType, que tipo debe ser, quiero obtener json o texto, resumiendo ¿Si quiero obtener Json en la respuesta debo enviar Json?

Espero ser claro, muchas gracias.

Comment: Estas tratando de implementar OAuth2?

Comment: si @devconcept, gracias por el aporte, lo voy a incluir en la pregunta

Comment: te recomiendo usar RestSharp para la authenticacion con Oauth 2 aqui tienes un ejemplo : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133937/how-to-use-oauth2-in-restsharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El spec de [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/) especifica que el Content-Type de tu request debe ser `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` en caso que la información de autenticación [se encuentre en el body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2). En tu caso haces un POST por lo que debes usar ese Content-Type para conformar con el estándard.

También especifica que el parámetro del body `grant_type` debe corresponderse de acuerdo con el flujo escogido con:

1. `authorization_code`: En caso que estés usando [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)
2. `password`: En caso que estés usando [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)
3. `client_credentials`: En caso que estés usando [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)

Por el código que pones imagino que estás usando Resource Owner.

Hay un pequeño detalle en tu pregunta y es que estás usando `id` y `secret` y esto [no es parte del estándard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-11.2.2). Deberías usar `client_id` y `client_secret` como medio de identificación

> Un cliente PUEDE usar el parámetro de la petición "client_id" para identificarse a sí mismo cuando le envía peticiones al endpoint del token.

Estos datos se envían en el body junto con los demás datos de autenticación. Tu código debería quedar así.

```
// Estos valores los obtienes usando input del usuario
var username = "john";
var password = "pass";

// Estos valores debes conocerlos de antemano para autenticar tu cliente
var clientId = "23343";
var clientSecret = "kjdhf343242j342";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sitio/webservices/auth/token/");

var postData = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret;

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

**Actualización**

Respondiendo a tu segunda, para decirle al servidor lo que quieres recibir debes usar un header Accept. El Content-Type de tu request no influye en lo que el server te enviará. Este header es para especificarle el **formato de lo que le estás enviando** y él pueda interpretarlo correctamente.

[Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

> El propósito del header Content-Type es describir los datos contenidos en el cuerpo lo suficiente para que el agente receptor pueda escoger el mecanismo o agente apropiado para presentar los datos al usuario

[Accept](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> El header Accept de la petición puede ser usado para especificar algunos tipos de datos o los tipos de medios que se consideran aceptables para la respuesta

Con este header le puedes especificar al servidor **en que formato deseas recibir la respuesta**.

Ten en cuenta que esto no siempre es posible ya que puede que el servidor no soporte el formato que le pides. Lee para más detalles

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation

http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers

Comment: me gusta esta respuesta, solo que creo que el texto transcripto de Content-Type y Accept debería estar en español.

Comment: Muy cierto. Enseguida lo edito. De todas maneras ya había incluido el link a la doc original.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas invocando un servicio REST aconsejaria evalues usar la clase `HttpClient` con este sera mas facil invocar servicio usando verbos http

[Obtain Bearer Token using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923325/obtain-bearer-token-using-httpclient)

[Logging into WebAPI 2 site from c# desktop application](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44097/logging-into-webapi-2-site-from-c-desktop-application)

en el ejemplo la parte importante

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(siteUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

 HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

 HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("Token", requestContent);
```

veras que se define en el `header` el `grant_type`, eso es importante. En tu ejemplo veo que defines `grant_type=grant_type` alli no defines ninguno.
Vas a obtener de respuesta un json que deberas parsear para obtener el valor del token