# Consumir Rest API en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest

Me gustaría que me pudieran guiar un poco con esto. Estoy tratando de consumir un API Rest en C# y tiene una autenticación donde debo pasarle estos parámetros o valores: `username`, `password`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `grant_type`, `scope` pero no sé cómo pasar esos valores.

Estoy haciendo algo asi:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("MiDireccionAPI") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; //"application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Headers.Add("username", "miUsuario");
request.Headers.Add("password", "MiClave");
request.Headers.Add("grant_type", "Migrant_type");
request.Headers.Add("client_id", "Miclient_id");

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Y se supone que el debería devolverme un *token* como este y un código `200`:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.UyHf8uJg3y6i0mKBlAsCpDKCfO_s5rASurzGgcBfc0Y8jm0cPPPZLNqKbQYXm0NUvpUVnNuC5O634cUFoOFlAOaAQwdnQbki34nXcRn9vb3YXj7bpOKmK1RFoB-Hf6rJ843VQQzC4vHxMUTOOa5k32gFNcWEnlVHclitGRZezJbozYeqCUi3VbzShMPKFAAT5gcDZgw6tgl7gbwiu4Mf4vCvJamKTfaziBBhj-3gVe5yXnEp-WfaH87B3rV9xM69SJ-EGJ1wxfUN3E7PTqjanYGDjA24UY-NRASwfJV9Gwyikk4irSGNCbAiRm70NCaGwFEMjzBetwp0avG0g_tu9Q
```

Pero me da error `400` porque imagino que el pasado de los parámetros está mal.

Si alguien me aclarar cómo pasar este tipo de valores a un API, ya que soy principiante en esto y no encontrado algo que realmente me sirva.

EDIT:

Tengo una web hecha en asp.net que hace facturas y debo consumir esta API y la cual usa OAuth 2.0, esta API es de una entidad gubernamental de mi pais que se encarga de recbir las facturas por esta api pero de esta API se debe generar un token para poder enviar lo que se ocupa.

Aca lo que estoy intentando es generar ese token para poder enviar las facturas.

Esta web se publica en un servidor.

[image: Asi se ve en el postman, pero no se como hacerlo para C#]

Comment: en base a los parametros me atrevo a suponer que esa API usa autenticacion basada en el protocolo OAuth

Comment: Sin la definición del API que intentas consumir es difícil saber qué es lo que está mal, además no comentas si lo deseas consumir localmente, o si ya está publicado en algún servidor, ¿me explico? Existen muchas variables a tomar en cuenta, no solo el envío de los parámetros. Estaría genial que editaras tu pregunta poniendo toda la información relevante de cómo intentas consumir el API.

Comment: Buen día, según lo que veo es que estas pasando los parametros como parte del header, solo pasalos como parametros en la URL.

Comment: En tu código original no veo que envíes el client_secret, sin embargo en el  postran lo incluyes. Puede ser eso?

Comment: al final te ha funcionado? cual ha sido la solucion?
Tengo exactamente el mismo problema. Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que el problema es que está enviando los datos en el body en postman, y el chico esta usando HttpWebRequest y enviando los datos desde el headers en c#, publica tu pregunta para ayudarte a resolverlo

Answer (score 4):

Explora la api a la que deseas conectarte utilizando alguna herramienta como [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), con ella puedes simular el **Request** de diferentes maneras hasta que descubras cuáles son los parametros exactos que necesitas, que tipo de request (GET,POST, ETC) y donde colocarlos (header, body, etc).

Ya con esa información es fácil crear un cliente.

Viendo tu ejemplo, modifícalo de la siguiente forma:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("MiDireccionAPI") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 

// Metodo modificado
string postData = "username=miUsuraio&password=MiClave&grant_type=password&client_id=Miclient_id";    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);  
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;  
using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream (){
    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(dataStream))
    {
        stmw.Write(postData);
    }
    dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  
}

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Se modifico el **grant_type**, cuando estas realizando la autenticación se le manda el grant_type = password para solicitar el token.

Otro punto a considerar es que si el servidor al que te estas conectando fue hecho con Web API 2 intenta buscar una url del tipo:

**http://dominio_del_servicio/Token**

Ya que la autenticación por default esta configurada a **/Token**

**EDIT:**

Cambie el ejemplo para usar POST en lugar de Headers.

Comment: Man, si use postman para ver el comportamiento y responde bien a la informacion que le coloco. Lo que no se es como en C# pasar los mismos parametros ya que en el postman los pongo en el body y el responde con el TOKEN que necesito y el codigo 200 (todo ok) pero en C# no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Arriba te coloque una imagen de como se ve en postman y todo trabaja correcto, lo que no se es en C# como le digo o como le paso cada uno de esos 6 parametros.

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que los parametros deben de ir como contenido del post y no en el header.

Comment: Agradezo el seguimiento que le das a mi post y por la ayuda que mi brindas. Yo encontre un ejemplo como ese que tu das en http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6151/c%C3%B3mo-debo-estructurar-una-solicitud-httpwebrequest-para-autenticarme-con-oauth    lo extraño es que en la linea donde dice HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;   se cae y por eso fue que probe la otra manera que coloque arriba.    Da este error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Comment: Actualize el codigo de nuevo, espero que con eso funcione.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes intentar implementarlo de esta forma, que es la que siempre uso y me resulta.

primero necesitaras el **Newtonsoft.Json** para des-serializar la respuesta y asi en caso de que te de errores puedas saber cual fue el error.
Lo instalas desde el gestor de paquetes NuGet
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para implementar la llamada a la api tambien necesitaras agregar las referencias a

```
System.Net.Http    
System.Net.Http.formatting
```

y con esto ya puedes usar este código, sustituyendo los valores que requieras enviar en los headers y el objeto que se tenga que enviar.

```
try
    {
        //declare api client 
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //Initialize api client
        if (client.BaseAddress == null)
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WS_URL"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Add headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X_PUBLIC_KEY", PublicKey.ToString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X_TIME", date);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X_TOKEN", CreateToken(PrivateKey + date, PrivateKey));

        //Call client.PostAsJsonAsync to send a POST request to the appropriate URI   
        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Vehiculo/Add", object).Result;
        //This method throws an exception if the HTTP response status is an error code.  
        //var xx = resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resultado = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<Vehiculo>().Result;
            return resultado;
        }
        else
        {
            var resultado = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultServer>(resultado);
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Message:{0}, ExceptionMessage: {1}", result.Message, result.ExceptionMessage));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("AddVehicle - Error: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
```

Espero te sirva de algo este código, y cualquier cosa sigo al pendiente.

Actualización...

Por lo que veo en la imagen de tu postman, los datos que envias en la llamada no son header, si no un objeto con los parametros username, password, etc...

entonces el problema es que en tu codigo estas añadiendo esos valores como headers. Lo que debes hacer es crear una clase que contenga esos parametros con el mismo nombre de como los estas mandando, y instanciarla asignandole valores, para mandarla en tu llamada a la api, lo cual en el código de ejemplo que te adjunte antes se hace en esta linea:

```
//Call client.PostAsJsonAsync to send a POST request to the appropriate URI   
        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Vehiculo/Add", object).Result;
```

Siendo object, la instancia a tu clase creada.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda, quedo al pendiente

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia el mismo problema tuyo y lo solucione con el código que genera Postman en distintos lenguajes 
La solución sería  algo  como esto:

```
const string URI_TOKEN = "https://login.micro......../oauth2/token";
const string CLIENT_ID = "Tu client Id";
const string GRANT_TYPE = "client_credentials";
const string RESOURCES = "https://Tu propia Url de recursos.com";
const string CLIENT_SECRET = "Coloca tus datos aqui";
const string URI_REQUEST = "La uri del servicio que quieres consumir";

var client = new RestClient(URI_TOKEN);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("Host", "login.microsoftonline.com");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
"------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\n" +
CLIENT_ID + "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\n" +
GRANT_TYPE + "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"resource\"\r\n\r\n" +
RESOURCES + "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\n" +
CLIENT_SECRET + "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

La siguiente linea es la que sirve para mandar los parametros de tipo multipart/form-data  `request.AddParameter (` los siguiente caraceres `------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW` es un concatenador como el `&` de los querystring.

Como comentas que los llamadaos desde tu postman te funciona bien, esta herramienta dá la opción de generar el código en distintos lenguajes.
Mira este  post donde te enseñan como hacerlo, ese código te servirá para que lo incluyas en tus Método de C#
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/
espero te  sirva y no sea muy tarde jejeje.  suerte

Comment: José, postman es sólo un cliente HTTP que nos ayuda a probar la funcionalidad de una API REST pero en este caso la pregunta dice que está intentando implementarlo en C#

Comment: @PakLeiChong lo que comenta aca es correcto, pero esto no deberia ser una respuesta, deberia ser solo un comentario

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Pak Lei Chong Edite la respuesta para que te resulte mas util, mensiono lo del postman porque el amigo que postio el problema menciona que el llamado dedsde esta herramienta si le funciona y si eso es asi  la herramienta tiene la funcion para generar codigo C# que haga lo que ella esta haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Según la imagen de Postman, los parámetros van el body NO el header como tú lo estás haciendo.

Te aconsejo esto:

```
           List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values =
            new()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", opt.ClientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", opt.ClientSecret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", opt.Scope),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", opt.GrantType),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", opt.Resource),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", opt.UserName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", opt.Password)
            };
```

luego:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent requestContent = new(values);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.PostAsync(requestUrl, requestContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez esto te puede servir como guía

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

http://ronaldrosiernet.azurewebsites.net/Blog/2013/12/07/posting_urlencoded_key_values_with_httpclient

```
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

aca deberias enviar tus datos.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te invito a que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ya que necesitas contextualizar mejor y simplemente colocas enlaces con un código y no das contexto de ello, también te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así ganas una [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) y aprendas más del sitio