# ¿Como consumir API REST desde ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

tengo el siguiente codigo que me permite consumir un API REST en Java script

```
  document.querySelector('#con').addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch("http://servername/consulta", {
            "headers": {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "authorization": "Bearer " + "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c" //El token es un ejemplo 
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Nombre del cliente: " + response.cliente_nombre1+" su DPI: " + response.cliente_ide  );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        
 } );
```

El cual ingreso de forma Exitosa, ¿Como podria hacer este mismo consumo a tra vez ASP.NET C#?

Comment: [Realización de solicitudes HTTP mediante IHttpClientFactory en ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) Aquí se encuentra toda la documentación para consumir un API REST usando un `HttpClientFactory` incluido como setear el Authorization Header mediante un `HttpMessageHandler`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Consumir Rest API en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60031/consumir-rest-api-en-c)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les agradezco por sus respuestas, adjunto la solucion que realice a base de la documentacion y aplicando conocimientos previos, espero les sirva en futuras ocasiones.

---

```
  public void metodoPost(){

       creacionCliente c = new creacionCliente() { dpi = 20200003, name = "Peter", lastNameOne = "Colorado", lastNameTwo = "Xitai", type = 3, bornDate = "1994-05-10" };
        var url = $"http://servername/consulta/registro";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJhbGciO...");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Se envia JSON");
        }
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (strReader == null) return;
                    using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                    {
                        string responseBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                        
                        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

te paso un ejemplo simplificado funcionando que utilizo equivalente a lo que pides:

```
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbGciO...");
  try
  {
     var response = client.Get("http://servername/consulta");
     string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsString();
     //opcional si quieres deserializar la respuesta en algun modelo utilizas la sgte linea
     //var consulta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Consulta>(apiResponse);
     //return ... 
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```

Te he pasado el ejemplo mas básico, esto obviamente se podría mejorar usando Async/await también y por supuesto como menciono el colega @Carlos Muñoz en los comentarios con HttpClientFactory usando *Dependency Injection*

Comment: Muchas gracias!!